# Problems building hadoop 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT on Windows 7 64 bits and Java 8 and Maven3.3.3

Tags: java, windows, maven, hadoop

When I use *Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt* building apache/hadoop 3.0.0 with the command of **mvn clean compile**.But I have some problems when the process go to here.How can I fixed this problem ? Many many thanks to you.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache Hadoop Common 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................. SUCCESS [  0.504 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Build Tools .......................... SUCCESS [  0.584 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM .......................... SUCCESS [  0.627 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations .......................... SUCCESS [  2.683 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM ..................... SUCCESS [  0.112 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies ........................... SUCCESS [  0.188 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ........................ SUCCESS [  1.092 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC .............................. SUCCESS [  1.873 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................. SUCCESS [  1.554 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ........................ SUCCESS [  0.400 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common ............................... FAILURE [  0.021 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ....................... SKIPPED

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.969 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-14T10:50:53+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 56M/269M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plu
gins:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\mingleiz\mygit\hadoop\hadoop-maven-plugins\target\
classes): No plugin descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginDescript
orParsingException
```

Comment: Could you please post your pom.xml?

Comment: Thank you bro,I have already solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sovle this problem just now.Following is my solution:

1:set Platform=x64 (when building on a 64-bit system)
2:install VS 2010 professional and SP1 is must need.

OK,and here is the ending for my building.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................. SUCCESS [  2.794 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Build Tools .......................... SUCCESS [  1.582 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM .......................... SUCCESS [  1.160 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations .......................... SUCCESS [  2.250 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM ..................... SUCCESS [  0.629 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies ........................... SUCCESS [  0.349 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ........................ SUCCESS [  2.902 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC .............................. SUCCESS [  2.578 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................. SUCCESS [  5.007 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ........................ SUCCESS [  2.580 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common ............................... SUCCESS [01:44 min]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS .................................. SUCCESS [  3.074 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS .................................. SUCCESS [ 22.619 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ....................... SUCCESS [  0.071 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Client .......................... SUCCESS [ 18.156 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................. SUCCESS [01:50 min]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS ............................... SUCCESS [01:09 min]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS BookKeeper Journal .............. SUCCESS [ 37.003 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-NFS ............................. SUCCESS [  1.932 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Project ......................... SUCCESS [  0.071 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN ................................. SUCCESS [  0.076 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN API ............................. SUCCESS [  9.896 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Common .......................... SUCCESS [01:24 min]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Server .......................... SUCCESS [  0.088 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Server Common ................... SUCCESS [  4.608 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN NodeManager ..................... SUCCESS [  8.123 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Web Proxy ....................... SUCCESS [  1.975 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN ApplicationHistoryService ....... SUCCESS [ 14.526 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN ResourceManager ................. SUCCESS [ 15.525 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Server Tests .................... SUCCESS [  1.688 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Client .......................... SUCCESS [  3.273 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN SharedCacheManager .............. SUCCESS [  1.601 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Applications .................... SUCCESS [  0.058 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN DistributedShell ................ SUCCESS [  1.453 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Unmanaged Am Launcher ........... SUCCESS [  0.789 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Site ............................ SUCCESS [  0.074 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Registry ........................ SUCCESS [  2.915 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Project ......................... SUCCESS [  0.170 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Client ..................... SUCCESS [  0.117 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Core ....................... SUCCESS [ 11.576 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Common ..................... SUCCESS [  6.131 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Shuffle .................... SUCCESS [  1.574 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce App ........................ SUCCESS [  8.106 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce HistoryServer .............. SUCCESS [  3.868 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce JobClient .................. SUCCESS [ 16.826 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce HistoryServer Plugins ...... SUCCESS [  0.649 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce NativeTask ................. SUCCESS [  2.308 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Examples ................... SUCCESS [  3.706 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce ............................ SUCCESS [  0.145 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Streaming .................. SUCCESS [  7.313 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distributed Copy ..................... SUCCESS [ 30.467 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Archives ............................. SUCCESS [  0.925 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Rumen ................................ SUCCESS [  4.658 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Gridmix .............................. SUCCESS [  3.211 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Data Join ............................ SUCCESS [  1.279 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Ant Tasks ............................ SUCCESS [  0.441 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Extras ............................... SUCCESS [  1.121 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Pipes ................................ SUCCESS [  0.063 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop OpenStack support .................... SUCCESS [  1.489 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Amazon Web Services support .......... SUCCESS [ 41.175 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Azure support ........................ SUCCESS [ 10.494 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client ............................... SUCCESS [  0.321 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Mini-Cluster ......................... SUCCESS [  0.165 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Scheduler Load Simulator ............. SUCCESS [  2.467 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools Dist ........................... SUCCESS [  0.356 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools ................................ SUCCESS [  0.051 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distribution ......................... SUCCESS [  0.109 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11:47 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-14T18:09:24+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 227M/583M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```